# Integrating Solarium in Zend Framework 1.12.3

Tags: zend-framework, solarium

Is there a method (easy or difficult, i don't care) to include Solarium in zend framework.
What i want is that i can use solarium everywhere in my application without causing any problems. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty Simple to follow instructions at [http://wiki.solarium-project.org/index.php/V3:Installation](http://wiki.solarium-project.org/index.php/V3%3aInstallation)

Step 1 > Create composer.json in your zend library folder

```
{
    "require": {
        "solarium/solarium": "3.2.0"
    }
}
```

Step 2 > Download composer from https://getcomposer.org/download/ and install it

Step 3 > Open command prompt and change your directory to the zend library folder.

Step 4 > Run "composer install" command, You will see the solarium package in vendors folder

Step 5 > Put following code in your bootstrap.php

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

Now you are ready to go test example scripts by solarium in any of the controller